# Error 500/OK in my jmeter load test and Apdex. What is the meaning of 500/OK?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0, apdex

Im load testing a microsft crm portal so after my load test, i extracted the logs and found out that I encountered a  500/OK error. If I may ask what is 500/OK error? Is this a valid defect of the application that I'm testing or is it a jmeter based defect?

Thank you :-)[errors encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWZ7H.png)

Comment: Can you show your response from server in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like application you are testing has encountered error and returned response with status code 500 and status OK.

In table you attached, first column shows ERROR CODE / STATUS TEXT...

You should report this to the developers and(or) examine application logs to check what went wrong.

Reference: [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)